# django: Two generic view in same template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I need some advice about generic views and template in Django. I am trying to figure out how it's works.

I want implement one page where I would like to display two generic view as CreateView and DeleteView.

For example:

**models.py**

```
class model(models.Model):
      name = models.CharFields(u'Name', max_length=30, null= True, unique= True)
```

How can I make one form for create object, and in same template below create form render table with all exist objects and use checkbox column like option for delete object.

Both of forms should consists button for submit action (Delete, Add)

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

in urls.py

```
from appname.models import model
from django.views.generic import list_detail
interface_info={
'queryset': model.objects.all(),
'template_name': 'template/interface.html'
}
url(r'^template/interface/$',list_detail.object_list,interface_info),
```

in template/interface.html

```
<form action="template/add/" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="template/delete/" method="get">
{% for a in object_list %}
{{a.name}}  <input type="radio" name={{a.name}}/>
<br/>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

your form is ready.

Comment: Hey sryy for late respond. I solved the problem in a similar way. I think You can't use in Django 1.5 'list_detail' generic view. Anyway tnx